# Create service instances with parameters in Service Fabric

Tags: c#, azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric, azure-iot-hub

I'm using Service Fabric on Azure for a project at work where, put simply, I have a service whose function is to read data from IoT Hub.

As it stands, that service is reading data from 32 partitions at the same time (multiple threads), but I'm trying to refactor it into one service intance per partition. The problem is I can't find a way to create 32 instances of a service and inform each instance of the Hub partition it should read (paramethers perhaps?).

I can provide code samples if needed, but I feel the problem is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Why not create a stateful service with 32 partitions instead? Each partition in the service would read from a single partition on your IoT hub. The other option is an application with 32 instances. You could put all 32 of those instances in the <DefaultServices> section - they would each need a unique name e.g. fabric:/MyApp/Service01, fabric:/MyApp/Service02, etc.

Comment: Actually you probably don't even need to use a stateful service with this. You could do a regular stateless service with 32 instances.

Comment: @Dismissile Your partitions idea worked! Feel free to post an answer and I'll accept it as the best one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a stateful service with 32 partitions. Each partition in the service would read from a single partition in your IoT hub. You could also do this as a stateless service that is a background worker (not a web api) that has 32 instances. You would need some way of coordinating which instance/partition is communicating with each IoT partition.

If you insist on have 32 instances of the service then you would just need to make sure that each instance of the service has a unique name. You could put these services in the  section of your ApplicationManifest:

```
<DefaultServices>
    <Service Name="Service01">
        <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="MyServiceType" InstanceCount="1">
            <SingletonPartition />
        </StatelessService>
    </Service>
    <Service Name="Service02">
        <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="MyServiceType" InstanceCount="1">
            <SingletonPartition />
        </StatelessService>
    </Service>
    ...
</DefaultServices>
```